# In Flask, is there a way to hide a @app.route from everyone but the app itself. My database can be seen from a url in JSON format

Tags: python, json, sqlite, url, flask

So I am working on a FLASK server, using sqlite3, json, axios and VUEJS. My VueJS frontend calls my sqlite3 database using axios. On the flask side the database is sent with jsonify over @app.route('/api/getdatabase', methods=['GET']). If I plug that url in the browser while my flask server is running I can see the entire database in JSON format from http://localhost:5000/api/getdatabase.

Is there a way to stop access to that url route from the browser while keeping that 'GET' connection to axios alive?

I attached the Flask @app.route and just in case the VueJs method that is calling 'GET' on that Flask route.

```
@app.route('/api/getdatabase', methods=['GET'])
def database_get():
        if request.method == 'GET':
                print("/getdatabase record")
                conn = sql.connect('test.sqlite3')
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATABASE ORDER By id")
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
                return jsonify(rows)
```

```
    getDatabase() {
      const path = "http://192.168.1.71:5000/api/getdatabase";
      axios
        .get(path)
        .then(response => {
          // console.log(res.data)
          this.database = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("Failed to get database");
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make that endpoint require authentication

```
from flask import make_response

@app.route('/api/getdatabase', methods=['GET'])
def database_get():
    if not request.headers.get('secret') == secret:
        return app.response_class(
            status=401,
            mimetype='application/json',
            response=json.dumps({'message': 'Invalid or missing secret'})
        )
```

Comment: In VueJS I just passed a header and made the Flask change:
axios
        .get(path, {
          headers: {secret: 'TACOBELL'}
        })

It works thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is a websocket.
see that:
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/